# Как изменить стиль прикрепляемого файла в dle в css

Tags: css, dle

Как изменить стиль attachment, какой класс, ид стиля за это отвечает?

Хочу изменить стиль ссылки на прикрепляемый файл.

Answer (score 1):

Конструкция вида `.ссылка[href$=формат]`стилизует ссылки у которых `href` заканчивается нужным форматом.

Например:

```css
.link[href$=pdf] {
    color: red;
}
.link[href$=xlsx] {
    color: green;
}
.link[href$=docx] {
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
<a class="link" href="file.pdf">.pdf документ</a>
<a class="link" href="file.xlsx">.xlsx документ</a>
<a class="link" href="file.docx">.doc документ</a>
```